# How many new patents were registered, commissioned or administered by NASA in 2016?

Tags: patent-applications

The question: "How many newly registered patents were filed by NASA during the fiscal year 2016?"

The answer may include any listing or database recently filed with the US Patent Office, its liaison with NASA or any NASA patent registry.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as patent applications are published after 18 months, normally, from a patent database side, there is no way to know yet.